# How to rebase git branch onto indirect parent branch when direct parent is merged

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-push, fast-forward

I have a feature branch say `branch A` and from A I have created `branch B`, later created `branch C` from B. Branch B got some more commits and got merged into branch A. I want to rebase branch C on branch A.

**Pictorial representation:**
Actual scenario
[image: actual scenario]

Expecting:
[image: expected scenario]

How do I achieve this? I've tried:

1. `git rebase A` when on `C`
2. `git rebase --onto A B C`

In both cases when I try to do `git push` I'm getting error:

```
! [rejected]            C -> C (non-fast-forward)<br/>
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/repo/myRepo.git'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-push%5D+non-fast-forward

Comment: `git push --force origin C`

Comment: @phd thanks it got resolved!